# Debian name wifi interfaces according to their drivers using udev persistent-net.rules?

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface, udev, interface

Hi I am working on Debian. Would like to name my wifi interfaces according to their driver

modifying `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-persistent-net.rules`

with:

```
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="test001"
```

where I can find the ? of `DRIVERS=="?*"` or better which part of `lshw -class network` should I use:

```
.....

.....
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlp5s0b1
       serial: 00:26:82:e7:b8:32
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.4.0-53-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.0.14 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: `brcmsmac` at least lshw show this.

Comment: @nobody like brcmsmac or "brcmsmac" ? sorry to bother not my field at all

Comment: you can copy it from your lshw output. `driver=brcmsmac` so it is `brcmsmac`

Comment: thanks !|!!!!!!!!!!!!